# Instance of BloC did not working independently

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have a list of forms, when the user enters valid information, it will automatically render another form. And I use a BloC list to manage the state for displaying images in that form. The problem is that when the import is complete and the previous form's content is cleared, the BloC will delete the previous form's image data even though the BloC instance is independent. I don't understand why that is. Here is my code:

```
                BlocBuilder(
                  bloc: indexCubit,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      children: List.generate(
                        listProduct.length,
                        (index) {
                          ShowImageCubit showImageCubit = ShowImageCubit();
                          List<File> imageFiles = [];
                          listCubit.add(showImageCubit);
                          listFiles.add(imageFiles);
                          return ProductInput(
                            key: UniqueKey(),
                            callBack: (val) {
                              print(val.images);
                              isUpdate = false;
                              listProduct[index] = val;
                              print(val.images);
                              indexCubit.change(Random().nextInt(100000));
                            },
                            dataUpdate: listProduct[index],
                            bloc: listCubit[index],
                            onDelete: () {
                              DialogItem.showMsg(
                                context: context,
                                title: 'Xác nhận xoá sản phẩm',
                                msg: "Bạn có muốn xoá sản phẩm này?",
                                onConfirm: () {
                                  listProduct.removeAt(index);
                                  listCubit.removeAt(index);
                                  listFiles.removeAt(index);
                                  setState(() {
                                  });
                                  // indexCubit.change(Random().nextInt(100000));
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            listFiles: listFiles[index],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                ProductInput(
                  disableValidator: true,
                  callBack: (val) => addProduct(val),
                  bloc: showImageCubit,
                ),
```

```
  clearInput() {
    print('===model===');
    print(model!.toMap());
    print('===model===');
    seriesCode.clear();
    warrantyCode.clear();
    // imageFiles.clear();
    showImage.clear();

    print('===model===');
    print(model!.toMap());
    print('===model===');
  }
```

```
checkSeri(val) async {
        delay.debounce(() async {
          await checkCode.checkCode(val!);
          // checkCallBack();
          if (widget.dataUpdate != null) {
            model = ModelProductOrder(
              id: widget.dataUpdate?.id,
              seriesProduct: seriesCode.text,
              warrantyCode: warrantyCode.text,
              images: showImage.images,
            );
            widget.callBack(model!);
          } else {

            if (checkCode.state.data == null &&
                checkWarrantyCode.state.data == null) {
              model = ModelProductOrder(
                id: widget.dataUpdate?.id,
                seriesProduct: seriesCode.text,
                warrantyCode: warrantyCode.text,
                images: showImage.images,
              );
              widget.callBack(model!);
              if (widget.dataUpdate == null) {
                clearInput();
              }
              // return;
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you **do** things in the build method. Creating objects, adding to lists. Do not do that. The build method can be called multiple times. Logic should not happen in the build method, but outside.

Comment: i understand you meaning which logic should be called outside? @nvoigt Can you give me some example more clearly? I can't find any function or logic can be take outside build method